# Paypal Questions - Charge Customer by Payer Id

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been looking around Paypal Restful API documentation and I haven't found documents that back up whether or not I can accomplish the following task. The question I have is

Can I charge a payer (by payerId) continuously without the use of Paypal subscriptions?

I come from using Stripe and want to integrate Paypal into my site but am not sure if I can do it the same way as Stripe. With stripe I used

```
$result = \Stripe\Charge::create(
[
    "amount"      => 100,
    "currency"    => "usd",
    "customer"    => $stripe_customer_id,
    "description" => "Order",
    "capture"     => false, //charge when I ship
]);
```

But with Paypal I have been using this

```
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('authorize')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

$payment->create($this->apiContext);
```

When I try adding a payerId it still needs me to go through the express checkout. How can I setup a charge and then capture it when I ship it if I need to go through the checkout.

Let me know of any documentation where they specify a way to do the above

P.S I am using the Laravel framework